# How to load all the list of file in Android Device using an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, file, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

How should I load the list of all the files present in an Android device. I have found many Stack Overflow posts showing how to recursively load all the lists of file but I have not be able to find out how to load the using a AsyncTaks.

This is how I am loading the list of all files.

But many time I get Null Pointer Exception at line number 111- `if(file.listFiles().length==0)`

```
 public class load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) 
        {

            load_items();

            return null;
        }

        public void load_items() 
        {

            getListFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()));
        }

    }
    private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if(file!=null && file.listFiles()!=null)
                {
                    if(file.listFiles().length==0) // Line 111
                    {
                      //DO Something                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
                    }
                }
            } else if(file.canWrite()){
              // Do Something       
               inFiles.add(file);           
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
```

I have not been able to figure out what is the error. Any help would be really Greatful.

Comment: "I have not be able to find out how to load the using a AsyncTaks" -- there is nothing special about doing this work from an `AsyncTask`. I suggest that you edit your question to include the complete Java stack trace, not just the error message. Also, you may wish to consider whether traversing all of external storage is the right solution to whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: `But many time I get Null Pointer Exception at line number 111- if(file.listFiles().length==0)`. That is because file.listFiles() can return null. Dont put all that code in one line. First check if null is returned. And if so then do not call .length.

Comment: Make sure that you are not using 32-bit JVM under 64-bit Windows. because in that case it will point to `Sys64`  folder, instead of `Sys32` and in that case it might throw NullPointerException.